# python how to use imp.find_module or alternative

Tags: python, autocomplete, module

I'm currently writing an autocompletion for python. Therefore I need to find the modules, that are imported.

This seems pretty easy with imp.find_module, but it doesn't work if I insert a path, which is important for an autocompletion. Inserting a path means, that it won't find the system modules.

The solution would be to get the PYTHONPATH and then, insert it. But that is really not a nice way to do it, since I just want the default path. Additionally PYTHONPATH is not even in my os.environ[].

Is there really no alternative to this complicated procedure? And if there is not, how can I get the default paths to the libraries?

Is there maybe even a better solution, which crawls automatically through the directories?

Note: Since I'm writing an autocompletion, I don't want to actually import/execute any code.

Comment: So you want to autocomplete an `import` statement with a custom module search path set and including standard/system wide modules?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But I want ultimately the source code of a file (if it is no library like 'time').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path of the standard libraries use:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', ...]
```

Using these paths you can search through them by using `os.listdir`, such as:

```
import sys, os 
standardlib = os.listdir(sys.path[n])
```

You will have check if you check if the path is a directory.

```
stdlibs = []
for lib in sys.path:
    if os.path.isdir(lib): 
        for module in os.listdir(lib):
            stdlibs.append(lib + "/" + module)
```

You might have to check this recursively and check for extensions.

This will get you the idea where to start.

You will also have to check your current directory (`os.getcwd()`) for files that can be a part of a package ([python package structure](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)).

Comment: That's not what this question is about. It's about finding modules that *could* be imported, but might be not. So the actual solution has to involve some directory traversal and stuff.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer now, because I don't really understand my own question anymore. However, following import paths is possible with `imp.find_module` and listing the python modules/packages in a directory (or all global modules) is pretty easy with `pkgutil.iter_modules`.